# Need help choosing a robust archive format

Tags: java, ftp, zip, tar

I'm working on a Java application that runs on Lubuntu on single-board computers and produces thousands of image files, which are then transferred over FTP. The transfer takes several times longer for multiple files than it does for a single file of the same size as the total of the multiple files, I'm assuming because the FTP client has to establish a new connection for every file. So I thought I'd have the application put the image files in a single archive file, but the problem with this is that sometimes the SBC won't shut down cleanly for various reasons, and the entire archive may be corrupted all the images will be lost. Archiving the files afterwards is not a great option basically because it takes a long time. An intermediate solution may be to create multiple midsize archives, but I'm not happy with it.

I wrote a simple unit test to experiment with `ZipOutputStream`, and if I cancel the test it before it closes the stream, the resulting zip file gets corrupted, unsurprisingly. Could anyone suggest a different widely recognized archive format and/or implementation that might be more robust?

Comment: Assuming the images are already compressed (PNG/JPG), then something like tar is probably better than trying to compress the images further - It'd probably be quicker

Comment: If the images are big, the connection overhead is likely to be very small in comparision.

Comment: @MadProgrammer right, further compression is not the purpose, and I was using zip only because it's readily available in Java, and with the compression level=0. In any case, while the images are being collected and saved, the speed is not a huge factor, although it's something to take into account. The main concern is robustness, i.e. having a readable archive after a crash.

Comment: @e4c5 They take several times longer to transfer than a single tar, it's not a question of "likely".

Comment: then you have a badly misconfigured FTP server. FTP sucks anyway. Why not use HTTP. A multipart post is a single transfer

Comment: For FTP, I was using vsftpd with the default configuration, and approximately the same ratio between one large and multiple small files holds for SCP, which is much slower overall due to SSH overhead on the relatively weak SBC, The issue with multiple small files seems to be pretty common. HTTP might work better, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tar format, [jtar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jtar/) implementation seem to work pretty well. If I cancel in the middle of writing, I can still open the archive at least with 7zip and even get the partially written last entry.